# CSS3 transition: can it move things around a screen?

Tags: css

even though it is not supported in all browsers, is it possible to use the CSS3 transition effect to move a line vertically or horizontally across the screen?

Comment: Yes. Do you really need a transition, or would you prefer an animation (sounds more logical in this case).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant by CSS3. Below is an example using animation not transition.

If yes using CSS3 `transform` & `rotate` along with `animation` (preferably by the use of @keyframes)

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/eHZKQ/7/

Comment: @gopi1410: thanks, i'm looking into animations but the fiddle you link to does not seem to do anything only display the text 'text'.....

Comment: the plan is for two lines to move and content open up inbetween - I have been looking at applying an accordion as my whole website but am having difficulty centering the animation and getting both lines to move so that the new content is in the centre - make any sense?

Comment: ok, I have it working now thanks - only thing is if I set it to a single iteration it works then all crams up the top - can I get it to play the animation once then keep the bars where they finished?

Comment: @Dan I have used -webkit in the fiddle, since I am using chrome. For ff, use have to use -moz prefix to see the animations in the fiddle. Yup you do that with css3 `animation-iteration count` (set it to 1) to play the animation once. & use `animation-delay` to bring the bars to whereever you want.